# Magento1.9 Rest Api filters

Tags: rest, magento, magento-1.9

How to get rest api data filterable by **updated_at** attribute in Magento1?

I would like my rest API data to be filtered by last updated_at so I have tried something like this:-
http://localhost/mage1/products?page=1&limit=5&filter[0][attribute]=updated_at&filter[0][gteq]=2019-09-01 07:40:30

I have tried the filters shown on devdocs for M1 but didn't succeeded with any proper result. https://prnt.sc/p0lrk9

Comment: ...and where is the question?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question @Sfili_81

Answer (score 0):

```
https://localhost/api/rest/products?filter[0][attribute]=updated_at&filter[0][from][0]=max_date&page=1&limit=100&order=updated_at&dir=asc"
```

This may help you.It worked for me

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To covince me otherwise, please explain in detail how this works and why it helps to solve the problem.